# Why does Xcode sometimes make something purple, and sometimes black?

Tags: xcode

Example:

```
scrollView.scrollEnabled = YES; //scrollEnabled appears black
scrollView.pagingEnabled = NO; //pagingEnabled appears purple
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Check your Fonts and Colors preferences.  Each color designates a different identifier category.

[alt text http://idisk.mac.com/cdespinosa/Public/FontsAndColors.png](http://idisk.mac.com/cdespinosa/Public/FontsAndColors.png)

The reason they're colored differently is that even though they are both properties on the UIScrollView object, the pagingEnabled identifier is also declared as an unsigned int bitfield member in the UIScrollView struct. That's causing it to be drawn in the Other Instance Variables and Globals color.

Answer (score 0):

What I've noticed is that I have a list of lines defining class variables, that the last line in the list is not color coded correctly.

```
NSMutableArray *answers;     // purple
NSMutableArray *etymologies; // purple 
NSMutableArray *questions;   // black
```

If I change the order, the last line is always black.
( Xcode 4.5.2 )